# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception Basic

Tags: java

When I Compile this program it has no errors, But when I run it I get an **Out Of Bounds Error**. Any Help? Thanks!

The Exact Error Is As Follows :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
>       at javaapplication.JavaApplication.main(JavaApplication.java:32)
>   C:\Users\Juwon\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

```
public class JavaApplication 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] grades = new int[4];
        grades[0] = 77;
        grades[1] = 84;
        grades[2] = 80;
        grades[3] = 96;

        String[] Students = new String[] {"Tom", "Ed", "Joe", "Bob"};
        double sum = 0.0;

        System.out.print("#\tStudent\tGrade\n");
        System.out.print("-\t-------\t-----\n");

        int i = 0;
        for(;i<grades.length;i++);
        {
            System.out.printf("%d\t%s\t%d\n", i, Students[i], grades[i]);
            sum += grades[i];
        }
        double average = sum / grades.length;
        System.out.printf("Class Average %f\n", average);         
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you posted same code ?

Comment: `for(;i<grades.length;i++);` semicolon terminates loop body, you have no loop - indent your code, and you'd see an anonymous block there. I see you tried to fix the error about `i` not being visible by moving it to above the block... that should not have been necessary.

Comment: *It compiles* only means it does not have syntax errors. It does not mean it does not have logic errors. Array index out of bounds means you've run off the end of the array (at either end).. Using the debugger to step through the code will show you where the problem is located.

Answer (score 1):

`for (; i < grades.length; i++);` <--- See the semi-colon at the end, basically this is executing all the code between the `)` and the `;`, which isn't much, meaning you could actually remove the loop with only a minor side effect to the code.

Instead, you should be doing something more like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {        
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.printf("%d\t%s\t%d\n", i, Students[i], grades[i]);
    sum += grades[i];
}
```

Note, now I can include `i` in the definition of the loop without issue

This is not a uncommon issue and one you will likely repeat a few more times in the future

Answer (score 0):

```
for(;i<grades.length;i++);
```

The semicolon is the troublemaker here. 
This leads to your variable i being more than the last index of the array. Hence the out of bounds exception!!

Answer (score 0):

As Elliot said, remove the semicolon from the end of your for-loop and your code should work fine. It's also common practice to initialize your counter variable inside the for-loop. The for-loop header should look like

```
for(int i = 0;i<grades.length;i++)
```